# onChange event doesn't change state in <select> React

Tags: select, meteor, onchange, reactjs

As the title, I have an `onChange` event for the `<select>` element in React, but it doesn't fire when I change the option in the dropdown.
I set the initial state, update the state with `this.setState()` and test it with 2 `onChange` event, 1 for the text input, and the other for the `<select>`.

Only the state of the text input is updated. It means only the text input called the `onChange` event.

Can anyone help me figure out why this happens?

```js
ServicesPage = React.createClass({
mixins: [ReactMeteorData],

getMeteorData() {
    var accountId = Meteor.userId();
    return {
        services: Services.find({ accountId: accountId }).fetch(),
        sites: Sites.find({ accountId: accountId }).fetch()
    }
},

getInitialState() {
    return {
        selected: "0",
        test: 'Hello'
    }
},

handleChangeLocation(e) {
    this.setState({ selected: e.target.value });
},

handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({ test: event.target.value});
    console.log(this.state.test);
},

componentDidMount() {
    $('select').material_select();
    console.log(this.state.selected);
},

render() {
    var sitesList = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < this.data.sites.length; i++) {
        sitesList.push(<option key={i} value={this.data.sites[i]._id}>{this.data.sites[i].name}</option>);
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <input type="text" value={this.state.test} onChange={this.handleChange} />
            <h4>Services Page</h4>
            <div className="row">
                <div className="col s12 m6 l6">
                    <select value={this.state.selected} onChange={this.handleChangeLocation}>
                        <option value="0">Choose location</option>
                        {sitesList}
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        )
    }
})
```

Comment: `$('select').material_select();`  what other plugin are you using ?
if you are using jquery plugin, so the onChange event wont be fired on the React onChange event . 
you have two options , 

1st :  
`$('select').change(function(e) { self.setState({value: e. value});`
2nd : 
Use a React Dropdown component , so The onChange event will be fired as you expect. here https://react.parts/web you can find react dropdown . 

Mixing jquery and React , is useful , but not considerd Best Practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`material_select` inserts it's own DOM elements and hides the existing `<select>` hierarchy. The React elements don't know anything about this since they work only at the level of the virtual DOM. Therefore `material_select` undermines the connection between the React virtual DOM and the real DOM.

This will be the case for almost all JQuery plugins, so they are mostly incompatible with React. You probably want to use the [material-ui](http://www.material-ui.com) React components instead.